# autocomplete is not working in ASP.NET MVC partial view

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, partial-views

I have a partial view with the textbox

```
<input type="text" name="models" id="models" />
```

In my script section of _Layout.csthml I have the script

```
$('#models').on('input propertychange paste', function () { 
    var target = $(this);
    target.autocomplete({
        source: function (request, response) {
            $.post(@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController"), request, response);
        },
        minLength: 1,
        delay: 1000
    });
});
```

However, when I enter some text in the input nothing happens, also no errors appear. I suspect that the reason is that #models does not exist yet when DOM is loaded. I was thinking about using global ajaxSuccess function but I am not sure if it a right thing to do. Will it be also called when I enter text in the input and go recursive? What is the best practice here?

I tried using ajaxSuccess like this:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
        $("#models").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/MyController/MyAction",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { searchText: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Text, value: item.Text };
                        }));

                    }
                });
            },
        });
    });
```

But got the error

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

I am sure that jQuery is loaded only once on the page and before my script. Intellisense does not see autocomplete function at all.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.autocomplete is not a function Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591155/autocomplete-is-not-a-function-error)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I was really stupid and did not realize that autocomplete is not a part of the main jquery package, but it's is inside jquery UI one.