# $()Autocomplete is not a function

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete

[image]Below is my code to render. i google out it and found that there may be mistake of jquery order. i changed it as given but still that is not work for me.

```
@model IEnumerable<UserManagementSystem.Models.UserDetail>
@using System.Linq
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {
        jQuery("#SearchName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/Home/Index",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                        }))

                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    })
</script>
<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p><br /><p>
    @using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Users", FormMethod.Get))
    {
        @Html.TextBox("SearchName", "", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", Style = "margin-right:10px;", placeholder = "Name" })
        @Html.TextBox("SearchEmail", "", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", Style = "margin-right:10px;", placeholder = "Email" })
        @Html.DropDownList("SearchDesignation", ViewBag.DesignationList as SelectList, "Select", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", Style = "margin-right:10px;" })  <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Users")'" />
    }
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Contact)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Designation)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Department)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Address)
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
@if (!Model.Any())
{
    <tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td>No Record Found</td><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr>
}
else
{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Contact)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Email)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Designation)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Address)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ID }) |
                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ID }, new { onclick = "return confirm('Are you sure you wish to delete this?');" })
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
}

</table>
```

all the above code is done in mvc 4.5.2, is there any problem related to .Net framework?. i am stuck over here and does not know what to do now. i also attach debugger error image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.autocomplete is not a function Error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591155/autocomplete-is-not-a-function-error)

Comment: Check your console for errors, I bet that will explain the problem.

Comment: `jquery-1.10.2.js` and `jquery-1.10.2.min.js`, use a single jQuery reference.

Comment: how can i found that there is duplication?

Comment: You read the code you wrote :) there are two consecutive lines with the same script, one minimized one not but in the end the same script.

Comment: i remove min.js but still i am getting error

Comment: Are you sure you're not using a custom build of jQuery UI that doesn't include the Autocomplete widget?

Comment: as per your guidance if i remove that js then also i face same error

Comment: open developer console of browser and go to network section of it. See what response code you get for `jquery-ui.js`. Is it 200 or 404. Make sure that `jquery-ui.js` get downloaded correctly on your HTML page.

Comment: Friends i have already attach console image here. please check it

Comment: Still not getting any solution

Comment: This error is solved but after solution of this error i have face another issue which is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38125952/mismatch-of-autocomplete-textbox-design/38139975#38139975