# Mismatch of Autocomplete textbox design

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc, jquery-autocomplete

i have used a ready made code and implement it in my project. now that code is working fine in one textbox and it is also get output. when i use it for another text box it was get the result from server side but somehow it wont display in client side.

```
@model IEnumerable<UMS.Models.UserDetail>
....
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
....
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "UserDetails", FormMethod.Get))
{
    @Html.TextBox("SearchName", "", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", Style = "margin-right:10px;", placeholder = "Name", id = "txtUserName" })
    @Html.TextBox("SearchEmail", "", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", Style = "margin-right:10px;", placeholder = "Email", id = "txtEmail" })
    @Html.DropDownList("SearchDesignation", ViewBag.DesignationList as SelectList, "Select", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2", Style = "margin-right: 10px; margin-top: 5px; height: 32px;" })  <input type="submit" value="Search" onclick="location.href='@Url.Action("Index", "Users")'" />
}
<table class="table">
    ....
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#txtUserName").keypress(function () {
        $("#txtUserName").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/UserDetails/SearchName",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    })

    $("#txtEmail").keypress(function () {
        $("#txtEmail").autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "/UserDetails/SearchEmail",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: { Prefix: request.term },
                    success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                        }))
                    }
                })
            },
            messages: {
                noResults: "", results: ""
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

above is my code for that. here i have attach two images. In one image you can see the result while in other only dot is display[image][image]

Comment: could it be inspect from form ?!

Comment: No, it generates dynamic ui tag in html

Comment: have u any error in console ?!

Comment: there is no error in console

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't write initialization code in events that occurs multiple times. Every time the event occurs it just re-initializes the widget instead of letting it do it's work. Your code should be:

```js
$("#txtUserName").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.ajax({
      url: "/UserDetails/SearchName",
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "json",
      data: {
        Prefix: request.term
      },
      success: function(data) {
        response($.map(data, function(item) {
          return {
            label: item.Name,
            value: item.Name
          };
        }))
      }
    })
  },
  messages: {
    noResults: "",
    results: ""
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution but i face error in second function i.e. in txtEmail function. i had implement your code but still i am facing that error.

Comment: well unless you provide the details of the error we can't help you.

Answer (score -1):

You can test it after success

```
 $(document).unbind('keypress');
```

Comment: do i need to write this code in success like this:                                 success: function (data) {
                        response($.map(data, function (item)   {$(document).unbind('keypress');
                            return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                        }))
                    }