# jquery - (...).autocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm currently working on a web application. 
There, I created a Textbox (Works with jquery autocomplete) which shows up when the user clicks on a button. 
Then I want to load the needed source for autocomplete from my database. But I'm currently testing it with some random values. 
When I call this:

```
            $("#docNameTB").autocomplete({
            source: ["Apple", "Banana"]
        });
```

The console says: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function"

Here are my script sources:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Here's my event code:

```
        function nextClicked() {
          $("#docNameTB").autocomplete({
              source: ["Apple", "Banana"]
          });
        }
```

And here's my Textbox:

```
               @Html.TextBox("docNameTB", "", new { @class = "form-control", @placeholder="Enter name here" })
```

Here's my button Press code:

```
            <a class="btn btn-default" id="nextButton" onclick="nextClicked()">Next &raquo;</a>
```

The solution of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591155/autocomplete-is-not-a-function-error) question didn't work for me. 
I only use the google places script source too and this is not a problem (I have tested it already):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places"></script>
```

Sry for my bad English and my formatting this is my first question.
:)
I hope somebody can help me!
Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Make sure you aren't loading jQuery.js again in page which would wipe out all the plugin methods contained in jQuery-UI

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.autocomplete is not a function Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591155/autocomplete-is-not-a-function-error)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I searched for another 3 hours in the Internet and I read, read and read.
And now I created my own solution, that worked for me. The trick was that I had to run autocomplete() on page load AND on button click.

Here's the Page load code:

```
    var docNameTB = $("#docNameTB");
    docNameTB.autocomplete({
        source: ["Banana", "Apple"]
    });
```

and here's the button click event code:

```
        function nextClicked() {
          docNameTB.autocomplete({
              source: ["Peach", "Ananas"]
          });
          // Other Code
        }
```

Maybe this is gonna help somebody too :)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**
**HTML Part**

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" onkeydown="nameSearch()" id="searchBox" placeholder="Search">
```

**JS PART**

```
function nameSearch()
{
$("#searchBox").autocomplete({
                source : ["Apple", "Banana"],
            });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your Reply but I still receive the error: "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function
    at nameSearch (SearchProfile:76)
    at HTMLInputElement.onkeydown (SearchProfile:70)"

Comment: <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>

Use this Sequence

Answer (score 0):

**Use this Sequences**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script src="yourJSFile"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I still have a question: Can you explain what I have to fill in "yourJSFile"?
- My JavaScript code isn't in an external file (Maybe that helps) -
I'm new at coding with JavaScript and JQuery

Comment: if you have separated js file then link it to here and if not then delete the line

Comment: I deleted the line so I have only these sources:

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDJ1nemqY0bYGDpH7eWdweGTE5nhHz4dF4&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">

but I still receive the same error

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/…; 
put this line in last

Comment: Thank you again for your quick answer.
Now I put the line "<script type="..." in last but I still receive the "(...).autocomplete is not a function" error.

Answer (score 0):

Use Jquery and Jquery UI CDn or Link at the head section

```html
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>
```