# Jquery UI - autocomplete is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I really don't know what I am doing wrong, I checked multiple answers but no success:

My scripts loading order:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js")
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/custom/cityGuessGameHome.js");
```

in custom js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetCities/',
        type: 'GET',
        success: function (result) {
            $("#cities").autocomplete({
                source: result
            });
        }
    });
});
```

> Uncaught TypeError: $(...).autocomplete is not a function

Scripts ordering is fine I guess, why do I get this error then?

Comment: this error already been solved in another post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19591155/autocomplete-is-not-a-function-error

Comment: Yes I saw that post, but I'm not loading any other js libraries aside from these 2.

Comment: try to use the live libraries instead of local ones and check if it does return the same

Answer (score 0):

Try below live js instead your local one:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```