# Why is this Javascript Error occurring in MVC Web application?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui

Okay I'm totally new to this so I'm not going to get a lot of the terminology right, but it's an ASP.NET MVC application where a create view is supposed to have an autocomplete function on the "StudentID" text box. It doesn't work. On the console window I get an error message "Autocomplete is not a function". This is strange because the intellisense at the beginning does give me autocomplete. I don't know what I'm supposed to paste below but I put in the javascript as well as the applicable Controller code. LMK if there's anything else you need to see. Thanks in advance.

P.S. If you know a better way to do autocomplete (this is done through a class that we got the code from some website and looks more complicated than similar things I did in the past) please let me know that too.

```
<script>
    $("#Student_FirstName").autocomplete(
    {
            source: function (request, response)
            {
            $.ajax(
                {
                    url: "/Enrollments/GetStudents",
                    dataType: "json",
                    type: "POST",
                    data:
                    {
                        term: request.searchTerm
                    },
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        response($.map(data, function (item) {
                            return {
                                label: item.Name, value: item.Name, id: item.id
                            };
                        }))
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 2,
            select: function (event, query)
            {
                console.log(query);
                $("#StudentID").val(query.item.id);
            }

    });

</script>
```

**And now from later on in the Create view:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StudentID, "StudentID", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Student.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new {@class = "form-control"}})
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StudentID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StudentID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

**And finally from the Controller Class:**

```
// GET: Enrollments/Create
public ActionResult Create()
{
    ViewBag.CourseID = new SelectList(db.Courses, "CourseID", "Title");
    ViewBag.StudentID = new SelectList(db.Students, "StudentID", "LastName");
    ViewBag.InstructorID = new SelectList(db.Instructors, "ID", "FirstName");
    return View();
}

// POST: Enrollments/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "EnrollmentID,Grade,CourseID,StudentID,InstructorID")] Enrollment enrollment)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Enrollments.Add(enrollment);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    ViewBag.CourseID = new SelectList(db.Courses, "CourseID", "Title", enrollment.CourseID);
    ViewBag.StudentID = new SelectList(db.Students, "StudentID", "LastName", enrollment.StudentID);
    ViewBag.InstructorID = new SelectList(db.Instructors, "ID", "FirstName", enrollment.InstructorID);
    return View(enrollment);
}
```

Comment: Are you including required javascript libraries? Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/19592566/3243074

Comment: Well, I'm pretty sure I included all the libraries that were done in the lesson. I thought it strange though that I was able to get "autocomplete" function on intellisense. But I'll double check that.

Comment: The sequence order is very important too.

Comment: Yeah but how can you tell what the right order is? I have jquery, jquery-ui, jqueryval, and autocomplete, in that order, in bundle.config. Shouldn't bundle.config start up when the project first loads? That link suggests moving the script to the end of the cshtml page so I'll try that.